# Chrome extensions disable reopening of an extension created tab

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I couldn't find any similar question to this, but is it possible to create a new tab within chrome extension (using `chrome.tabs.create`) and then after closing it using the same extension prohibit user from reopening it using `ctrl+shift+t` or undo close tab command?

Answer (score 1):

You can open an incognito tab; it will have the requested behavior.

I don't think you can clear session data, and simply clearing history does not prevent reopening.

Comment: That's what i thought - thanks for the answer tho :)